# Повторный запуск setInterval

Tags: setinterval, функции, clearinterval, javascript

В начале функции сначала нужно останавливать setInterval qweqwe, а потом запускать.

Сейчас он только останавливается, но не запускается...

```
function qweqwe() {
 clearInterval(qweqwe);
 qweqwe = setInterval(function() {
  ...
 }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function qweqwe() {
    clearInterval(qweqwe);

    qweqwe = setInterval(function() {
        alert(1);
    }, 1000);
}

qweqwe();
```

Всё прекрасно работает :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var handle;
function qweqwe() {
 clearInterval(handle);
 handle = setInterval(function() {
  ...
 }, 100);
}

qweqwe();
```